# get data from a form to insert data id from table a into data id from table b

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am new @ php PDO mysql and trying to create my old access db into mysql with a frontend.

my tables are the following:

```
table a: devices_type.
table b: devices.
```

I need a user to select from the option box some data from table 'a' so we can tell the script to use the corresponded ID from table 'a' in to the ID from table 'b' (together with for example the serial number of the device.

This is the code i already have:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    require "../config.php";
    require "../common.php";

    try 
    {
        $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

        $nieuwe_device = array(
            "devices_serial" => $_POST['devices_serial'],
            "devices_date"  => $_POST['devices_date'],
            "devices_type_id" => $_POST['devices_type_id'],
        );

        $sql = sprintf(
                "INSERT INTO %s (%s) values (%s)",
                "devices", 
                implode(", ", array_keys($nieuwe_device)),
                ":" . implode(", :", array_keys($nieuwe_device))
        );

        $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute($nieuwe_device);
    }

    catch(PDOException $error) 
    {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
    }

}
?>

<?php require "templates/header.php"; ?>

<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $statement) 
{ ?>
    <blockquote><?php echo $_POST['devices_serial']; ?> is succesvol toegevoegd.</blockquote>
<?php 
} ?>

<h2>Nieuwe Devices</h2>

<form method="post">
    <label for="devices_serial">Serienummer</label>
    <input type="text" name="devices_serial" id="devices_serial">
    <label for="devices_date">Datum</label>
    <input type="date" name="devices_date" id="devices_date">
<select>
        <option value= name="devices_type_id" id="devices_type_id"></option>
</select>
    </br></br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button">
</form>
<form method="get" action="index.php">
    <button type="submit" class="button">Home</button>
</form>
</br></br>
<?php require "templates/footer.php"; ?>
```

I tried to put a separed sql query like

```
<?php $sql: "select devices_type.devices_type_id, devices_type.devices_type_model from devices_type join devices on devices_type.devices_type_id = devices.devices_type_id?>
```

with the value of the option box.
It is not working, i am stuck on this for a week. Does anyone know a trick for this?

Comment: another thing i tried was whit a second db connection, then the values are selectable but i always get an error on the insert that devices_type_id my not be empty

Comment: Now that you're using PDO, use it the right way -- with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). Don't build queires with `sprintf()`.

Comment: hello Alex, thanks for the answer i will take a look @ it to c if i can find a solution whit that.